Как на плагине woo_wallet изменить цену с помощью mysql?
На самом вордпрессе код выглядит таким образом:
woo_wallet()->wallet->debit($getcurrentuserid, $tzidprice, $details);

А мне нужно в обычном mysql. Как это делать? Не нашел в phpmyadmin, искал по балансу.

Никогда не нужно работать с ВП "с помощью mysql". Если, конечно нет стойкого желания поломать сайт, а вслед за ним и бизнес клиента. Нужно использовать функции ВП. (А ещё лучше готовые, проверенные плагины из оф репо)
